# Is any (Laurent)polynomial that is symmetric and $f(1)=1$ the Alexander polynomial of some knot?

Tags: algebraic-topology, knot-theory

I found the statement this theorem on wikipedia but I could not get any further information. How is this possible? Could you please give me some further reference? Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

See Theorem 5 on page 171 of Rolfsen's *Knots and Links*.  The general idea is that you can do surgery in the complement of the unknot, where the surgery solid torus is knotted according to the coefficients of the Laurent polynomial.  When you have a surgery curve that has linking number $0$ with an unknot, the infinite cyclic cover of the resulting knot after surgery has a nice description.

A reference with another description of these sorts of infinite cyclic covers is Lickorish's *An Introduction to Knot Theory*, page 70.

Comment: Is there an approach relies more on Seifert surface?

Comment: I don't know how to do this yet, but the surgery should take the Seifert surface for the unknot (a disk) and transform it into a Seifert surface for the resulting knot.  However, the point of the infinite cyclic cover description is that it is not too difficult to read off the Alexander polynomial, and it seems like it would be more difficult to deal with the Seifert surface directly.  I'd be interested to know if there were a way to use the Alexander-Conway skein relation to convert a polynomial into a knot.